# Multiple coverage reports and badges for GitLab Tests

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In our mono repo, hosted on a GitLab server, we have multiple types of tests, e.g., for

1. C,
2. Pyhton, and,
3. Java,

that run in a CI/CD pipeline setup (GitLab is version **v16.8.1**).

For all these tests a Cobertura coverage XML report is created. The `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks something like this:

```yaml
test_c:
  stage: test
  coverage: '/TOTAL\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\d+%)/'
  script:
    - ./test_script_c.sh
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: build/tests/c/CoberturaCoverageScripts.xml

test_python:
  stage: test
  coverage: '/TOTAL\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\d+%)/'
  script:
    - ./test_script_python.sh
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: build/tests/python/CoberturaCoverageScripts.xml

test_java:
  stage: test
  coverage: '/TOTAL\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\d+%)/'
  script:
    - ./test_script_java.sh
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: build/tests/java/CoberturaCoverageScripts.xml
```

This has now the downside, that

1. only **one** coverage number is reported on the landing page of the repostiory,
2. only **one** coverage number is reported on the MR, and
3. only **one** coverage  badge is created on the landing page of the repostiory,

Especially on the MRs, this is quite bad. As I only know that the overall project test coverage is like that, but I would need to know that the most important coverage (e.g., C) has not gotten worse and is not catched by an improved test coverage in the e.g., Java part of the project.

[GitLab CI Test Coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pRGV.png)

Is there an option to have all three coverage reports shown on at least the MR, i.e., find a setup for the GitLab CI/CD pipeline that shows multiple test coverage numbers.